# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end after refactoring IF/ELSE

Tags: ruby

I refactored this code:

```
if @data.class == Fixnum
  bin_num = @data.to_s(2)
else
  return results
end
```

To this:

```
@data.class == Fixnum ? bin_num = @data.to_s(2) : return results
```

And my program is getting the error in the title. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
bin_num = @data.to_s(2) if @data.class == Fixnum or return results
```

Comment: Did I make a mistake in the way I wrote mine? Or is that the way I should write it because of the return?
This way it worked btw. Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing you are inside a method and you want to either set some value to `bin_num` or to return from that method.

Comment: Yeah exactly. I need it to exit.

Comment: So you can't use a ternary for flow control in Ruby ... you'd have to use `and/or` which is a bit different
I suggest you read this http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
return results unless @data.class == Fixnum
bin_num = @data.to_s(2)
```